# Azure B2B External Identities

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, idp

I've set an External Identities on my Azure AD B2B (`Azure Azure Active Directory > External Identities > All identity providers > New SAML /WS-Fed IdP`)
I setup a SAML configuration as the screenshot below:
[External Identity configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45D8s.png)

When I try to define a new User flow my extenal identity isn't present in External Identity provider list, the only two options are

- Azure Active Directory Sign Up
- Microsoft Account

How can I add my external identity in this list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SAML/WS-Fed IdP federation is a public preview feature of Azure Active Directory. For more information about previews, see [**Supplemental Terms of Use for Microsoft Azure Previews**](https://azure.microsoft.com/support/legal/preview-supplemental-terms/).

> **Public preview** – During this phase we allow any customer with the proper Azure AD license to evaluate the new feature. Microsoft
> Customer Support Services will supply support services during this
> phase, but normal service level agreements do not apply. For new
> features exposed in the Azure AD Portal, customer can expect to see
> information banners in the user interface that draw attention to the
> new experience available during the preview. By clicking on the
> information banner customers then opt-in to the preview experience.

Would suggest to reach out [MS Support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request) and get the proper Azure AD licence for experience this Azure Preview Feature

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/direct-federation

Comment: Thank you, i will chek with MS Customer Support